# Which books are the moments from Skyfire Cycle of Brooklyn 99 based on?

Tags: story-identification

In the popular show Brooklyn 99, a fantasy series with the name Skyfire Cycle is repeatedly referred to.

The favourite moments shared by two of show's leading actors are as follows:

- Summoning of Balakastro
- The scarlet feast
- When you thought Ka'lar had been swallowed by the Norolith, but had just switched armor with Samling the Betrayer in the battle of Vorcastle.

I am looking for which books these specific events are based on. While the scarlet feast points to the "Red Wedding" of A Song of Fire and Ice, the rest of the moments do not resemble anything to me.

To prevent it from migrating to other SE sites, I am not interested in the producers' or writers' comments unless they directly state the answer of this question. I am looking for name resemble and event association.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For my money they're too generic to identify.

The armor swapping is an old trope (Patroclus wearing Achilles armor into battle, and Hector killing him thinking he was Achilles).

"*When you thought Ka'lar had been swallowed by the Norolith*" the surprise escape from death / resurrection that we see everywhere from Gandalf to MacGyver to
Ronan the Accuser, there's nothing unique about them.

That they're such obvious tropes and are so generic is an in joke to how terrible the books must be.

As you say, the "scarlet feast" is an obvious nod to the red wedding, and shows how deeply that has been embedded in our psyche . . . but there's nothing in there other than that.

Comment: I upvoted it but I believe the name resemblance might provide more information. I will wait some more before I accept it.

Comment: In general I would say the Skyfire series is a parody of ASIAF.  The author (in the show) bears a certain resemblance, in his demeanor and dress, to GRRM as well, I think.  I do agree that these other two examples are just generic tropes though, probably not specific references to ASIAF or any other particular work.  Particularly the Balakastro thing... I mean apart from the fact that he was "summoned" we know *nothing* about that character, I don't think.

Comment: It's like a perverted magic eye painting, you look and look and can't see anything, then you see FAR TOO MUCH. e.g. Balakastro is an anagram of "A Boar Talks", which totally applies to the author, but then you could go mad trying to find meaning in these nonsense names :)

Comment: @Steve-O It feels like so many things were mixed up in Skyfire Series. Dragons and prophecy points directly to Asoiaf. The armour swapping may also be about the Garlan Tyrell wearing Renly's armour to confuse Stannis' soldiers.Yet, it also has elves, something clearly has nothing to do with Asoiaf.

Comment: @C.Koca I agree, it's pulling from all sorts of fantasy sources, some specific references and others just generic "fantasy tropes."  Terry's cosplay barbarian seemed like a fairly obvious reference to Conan, for example.  Or a blend of Conan and He-Man, if you prefer.  I'd say it broadly parodies ASIAF, but it's certainly not limiting itself to that material alone.